# Can't start Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm trying to run cqlsh to connect to cassandra and received the following error messages.

a) error from cqlsh running:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

b) error message after running cassandra:

```
Exception (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError) encountered during startup: null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:709)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$9.execute(StartupChecks.java:351)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify(StartupChecks.java:109)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:607)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:717)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad configuration; unable to start server: At least one DataFileDirectory must be specified
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:846)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<clinit>(Keyspace.java:66)
    ... 6 more
ERROR 00:27:05 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:709) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$9.execute(StartupChecks.java:351) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify(StartupChecks.java:109) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188) [apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:607) [apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:717) [apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad configuration; unable to start server: At least one DataFileDirectory must be specified
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:846) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<clinit>(Keyspace.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

c) brew status shows that there's an error running cassandra instance:

```
Name          Status  User   Plist
cassandra@2.2 error    /Users/john/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.cassandra@2.2.plist
rabbitmq      stopped        
redis         started  /Users/john/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
tomcat@7      stopped
```

Can anyone please help on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is thrown from [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/DatabaseDescriptor.java#L1344) - it means that you don't have configuration option `data_file_directories` that [specifies](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cassandra.yaml#L203) where Cassandra need to store the data, and it looks like that `$CASSANDRA_HOME` is not set.

Open the `cassandra.yaml` file, uncomment `data_file_directories` configuration option and next line, and point to the directory where Cassandra can write the data instead of default `/var/lib/cassandra/data`.  Most probably you'll need also specify other parameters, such as, `commitlog_directory`, `hints_directory`, and `saved_caches_directory`.